# How to fix In emoji_id: Value "" is not snowflake

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to send a message in a specific channel and give it two reactions, but it gives me this error:

> value "" is not snowflake

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def todo(ctx, *, todo):
    channel = bot.get_channel(977358109607608330)
    message = await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has suggested: \n{str(todo)}")
    await message.add_reaction(":thumbsup:")
    await message.add_reaction(":thumbsdown:")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@bot.command()
async def todo(ctx, *, todo):
    channel = bot.get_channel(977358109607608330)
    message = await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has suggested: \n{str(todo)}")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
```

If you want to get certain emojis you need to type a backslash infront of the emoji name and then post it to any channel.

Like this for example:

[image]